# See files affected by previous commits in bzr

Tags: bazaar

When using bazaar you can easily see uncommited changes with the **bzr diff** command. You can also see changes since a specific revision, or use bzr status to see the filenames only.

```
bzr diff -c 2169
bzr status -c 2169
```

Instead of looking for a specific commit number, using **bzr log** is there a simple way to look at all changes in a number of commits, the previous 2 commits for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can view log of the previous 2 commits like this:

```
bzr log -l2
```

You can view all the logs from a specific revision until the end with:

```
bzr log -r2169..
```

You can of course specify an end range as well.

You might also find useful some interesting revision specifiers for example `last:N`. You can view the diff or status of the last 2 revisions with:

```
bzr diff -rlast:3
bzr status -rlast:3
```

You can read more about revision specifiers in `bzr help revisionspec`.

Let me know if you were looking for something else.

Comment: bzr status -rlast:n is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `verbose`. With `--verbose (-v)`, bzr log will print all affected paths.

To get the files affected **only in last commit**, use

```
bzr log --verbose -l1
```

To get the files affected is **level of commits**, use

```
bzr log --verbose -l<level-of-commit>
```

To get the files affected in **specific commit**

```
bzr log --verbose -r<rev-of-commit>
```

you can use either flag `--verbose` or `--v`